# Jetty: How do I protect unpack war file

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jetty, embedded-jetty

I developed web that deploy ROOT.war through jetty(windows10)

and I will deploy that to my client

but I don't want to who modify my unpacked war file.

and I want to protect my unpacked war file

Someone tell me How do I protect unpacked war file

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard filesystem protections is the only way.

Jetty runs on as a specific user against it's own private temp/work directory which no other user has access to.